# Tooltip in JavaFX not working?

Tags: javafx

I am unable to get tooltip working on mac at all. It ain't showing no matter what I do.  I have tried both adding a tooltip element in the scenebuilder

[image]

and

manually in the code like:

```
public class JavaFXApplication13 extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Button btn = new Button();
    btn.setText("Say 'Hello World'");
    Tooltip tooltip = new Tooltip();
    tooltip.setText("asd");
    btn.setTooltip(tooltip);

    StackPane root = new StackPane();
    root.getChildren().add(btn);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

}
```

Tested the exact same code on Windows, works great...

Comment: Please post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that exhibits the problem.

Comment: It's added now in the question.

Comment: Works fine on my Mac (Java 1.8.0_20, OS X 10.8.5)

Comment: If I connect my USB hub with an external mouse, it doesn't work, but if I only use mousepad without usb hub connected, it works great??

Comment: Okay after some research I actually have found out that my mouse is to blame.. If I unlplug my mouse, tooltips shows up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this if anyone else wonder is because I used a RAT 7 mouse by Cyborg. Without the software from Cyborg, the mac for some reason thought that the mouse was constantly moving. After the software was installed the tooltip shows.